# APACHE mod_rewrite add query string to URL

Tags: apache, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, httpd

Using mod_rewrite how can I change the current URL format:

- From: `https://example.com/something/NAME-IN-CAPS/phonebook.xml`
- To: `https://example.com/anything/whatever/phonebook.php?name=NAME-IN-CAPS`

Comment: Out of interest why would you want to add the string? most people want to remove it for user experience and SEO.

Comment: I want to get the phonebook via the php script, i put the name of the user i want to fetch, but the phone is always trailing any url as /phonebook.xml and thats why I need something like this.

Comment: Does the "current URL format" actually return a valid resource?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the following example, and rewrite the words `something`, `anything`, and `whatever` to your actual directory names:

```
RewriteRule something/([-A-Z]+)/phonebook.xml anything/whatever/phonebook.php?name=$1
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what i was looking for, i modified a little bit the regex, but its fine. Thanks.